# Post Moved to Rasberry Pi Site

Tags: discussion, migration

Originally I made this question on the Electrical Engineering site but it was migrated to the Rasberry Pi site.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36627/34975

It was later closed as off topic on the raspberry pi site - a decision I agree with as it the fact my scenario uses a Pi really has no bearing on the question posed.

So is the question I asked off topic for this site as well or was someone being a bit over zealous?

Comment: I figured that the dedicated Raspberry Pi enthusiasts would know Raspberry Pi power requirements better than us general EEs.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: It clearly wasn't a question about what the power requirements are, but rather on how to provide the power.

Comment: Mass migrations to Arduino or RPI based on the word "Arduino" and "Pi" seem to be very common, and against the community decided policy here, but it's ignored often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Nick tends to knee-jerk migrate any post that merely mentions Raspberry Pi or Arduino, without considering whether the question is really appropriate for the destination site.

I've undeleted, reopened and edited [your original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/191535/11683), and added a comment. Note that it is still borderline off-topic, since it's really about the use of existing devices rather than electronics design. But I'm going to err on the side of calling it a system-level design question. Let's try to keep it from crossing the line.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your rules

Comment: My decision was a sum of: *Off-topic → Use [close to that]* and *Duplicate of [Olin's guide to choosing power supply](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)*.  Then the choice was: close the question here, or give it another life on RPi.SE .  The second option seemed more clement.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to migrate a question you feel like closing. Statistically, interesting questions get answered on the site where they're asked, while not-so-interesting questions get migrated, which creates negative attitude towards migrated questions on the other side.

Comment: @DaveTweed  Your opening statement doesn't agree with statistics.  Not that many questions tagged [tag:arduino] get migrated or Arduino.SE.  Today, this number is on the order of 10%.  In Oct 2015 this number was higher, but not greater than 25%.  If it were indeed a knee-jerk, this proportion would be much greater.